# App began to crash on iOS 9.1 Beta 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7.1beta, ios9.1

The application began to crash when installing on iOS 9.1 Beta 2. **Exactly  same binary (downloaded from hudson link)** behaves so:

- It did not crash on iOS 9.0 and iOS 9.0.1
- It did not crash on either iOS 8

I have extracted the crash log, crash happens inside the call to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameOfView" owner:self options:nil];`. The crash itself is `NSUnknownKeyException`:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< NameOfView: 0x1446a6ea0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .'

So far i see weird key `'.'` which nib loading mechanism tries to set on my class, and obviously, such is not present in nib. And this looks extraweird even more, due to iOS 9.1 beta 2 is the only version with this behaviour. Moreover, building app with XCode 7 from on same git revision gives no success crashing app - it works as expected. Has anybody experienced such behaviour after trying your release versions on iOS 9.0.1 beta 2? Want to have some feedbacks of SO community before file a bug to radar. Appreciate your help, guys.

**P.S. I'd like to emphasize that the issue reproduces only on that particular binary. Building it again from the same sources in XCode 7 doesn't produce a crash. So please, don't suggest how to debug such kind of problem, how to set exception breakpoint etc.**

**EDIT**
Since 9.1 release, it's no more reproducible.

Comment: It's a beta.  Have you raised a bug report about this?

Comment: Filed bug at Apple and openradar http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6294934587965440

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comment to original question, there's no solution and no response on bug yet.

The openradar link: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6294934587965440

I'll be posting an updates here after the 9.1 release.

There are some empiric ways to come up with solution:

1. Override KVC setter `setValue:forKey:` and forbid empty string
   key.
2. Use always the latest stable SDK to build.

But again, no actual response from Apple neither.

**EDIT** Since 9.1 release, it's no more reproducible.